# Using `async def` vs `def` in FastAPI and testing blocking calls

Tags: python-asyncio, fastapi, uvicorn

### `tl;dr`

1. Which of the options below is the correct workflow in `fastapi`?
2. How does one programatically test whether a call is truly blocking (other than manually from browser)? Is there a *stress testing* extension to `uvicorn` or `fastapi`?

I have a number of endpoints in `fastapi` server (using `uvicorn` at the moment) that have long blocking calls to regular sync Python code. Despite the documentation (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/) I am still unclear whether I should be using exclusively `def`, `async def` or mixing for my functions.

As far as I understand it, I have three options, assuming:

```py
def some_long_running_sync_function():
  ...
```

#### Option 1 - consistently use `def` only for endpoints

```py
@app.get("route/to/endpoint")
def endpoint_1:
  some_long_running_sync_function()


@app.post("route/to/another/endpoint")
def endpoint_2:
  ...
```

#### Option 2 - consistently use `async def` only and run blocking sync code in executor

```py
import asyncio


@app.get("route/to/endpoint")
async def endpoint_1:
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  await loop.run_in_executor(None, some_long_running_sync_function)


@app.post("route/to/another/endpoint")
async def endpoint_2:
  ...
```

#### Option 3 - mix and match `def` and `async def` based on underlying calls

```py
import asyncio


@app.get("route/to/endpoint")
def endpoint_1:
  # endpoint is calling to sync code that cannot be awaited
  some_long_running_sync_function()


@app.post("route/to/another/endpoint")
async def endpoint_2:
  # this code can be awaited so I can use async
  ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since no one is picking this up I‘m giving my two cents. So this stems only from my personal experience:

**Option 1**

This completely defeats the purpose of using an async framework. So, possible, but not useful.

**Option 2** and **Option 3**

For me it‘s a mixture of both. The framework is explicitly made to support a mixture of sync and async endpoints. Generally I go with: No `await` in the function/CPU-bound task -> `def`, IO-bound/very short -> `async`.

**Pitfalls**

When you start using async programming it‘s easy to fall for the fallacy that now you don‘t have to care about thread-safety anymore. But once you start running stuff in threadpools this isn‘t true anymore. So remember that FastAPI is running your `def` endpoints in a threadpool and you are responsible to make them threadsafe.

This also implies that you need to consider what you can and can‘t do with your event loop in `def` endpoints. Since your event loop is running in the main thread, `asyncio.get_running_loop()` will not work. This is why I sometimes define `async def` endpoints, even if there is no IO, to be able to access the event loop from the same thread. But of course then you have to keep your code short.

As a side note: FastAPI also exposes starlettes `backgroundtasks`, which can be used as a dependency to create tasks from endpoints.

As I‘m writing this, this seems pretty opinionated, which is probably a reason why you didn‘t get a lot of feedback until now. So feel free to shoot me down, if you disagree with anything :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @thisisalsomypassword - I fully agree with Option 1 defeating the purpose of `fastapi`. Now with Options 2-3 is the only difference whether the entire endpoint runs in a separate executor (Option 3) or that only long-running tasks run in a separately declared executor (Option 2) - essentially facading over sync and treating it as async (with `await` from the executor)?

Comment: Yes, I think that‘s basically it. As you said, the executor is „separately declared“. So the details of how your work is sent to a thread are of course a bit different. If there is nothing else IO-bound going on in `endpoint_1` in „Option 2“, I wouldn‘t declare it as `async def`.